# nodemailer fails on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, authentication, invalidation, nodemailer

I trying to send an email using node.js and the module node-mailer on heroku, but it is failing. I show you the code I have (I think simple), and after I´ll explain better.

```
var nodemailer  = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'example@gmail.com',
        pass: 'pass'
    }
});
exports.sendAnEmail = function(receivers, tittle, user, message, jsonBack, callBack)
{
    var mailOptions = 
    {
        from: "User example@gmail.com", // sender address
        to: receivers,
        subject: tittle, // Subject line
        html: message // html body
    };
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, response)
    {
        if(err)
            console.log("email.js->sendAnEmail-> error: " + err)
        else
            console.log("email.js->sendAnEmail-> NO error")
        if(callBack && typeof(callBack)=="function")
            callBack();
    });     
}
```

If I execute this code (or rather, the code that invoke that) on local it works fine, but if I execute (on the git console) heroku run cron (it will be a schedule task on heroku), the console spits this: **"email.js->sendAnEmail-> error: Error: Invalid login"**.
I tryed to access my account coying and pasting the user and the pass and it let me in.
Do I need to do something else using heroku (or using schedule) to make it works??

Thank you.

Comment: I found the seed of the reason why gmail doesn´t give me access... when I try to send a mail, I recive on the gmail sender account a notification about there was a attempt to access to this account from California, and google recognizes it as a suspicious start session. One of the things I discovered to do is go this link [unlockCaptcha](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) and enable the access account... and it works :) ... but only over 20-30 seconds :.( after this time... I get the same error. Any suggestion??

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. Worked well.

Comment: TY same here! So far it's still working way more than 30 seconds later, hopefully I won't run into the repeating errors like you did.